# Python check if a list of nodes are all in the same connected component in O(n)

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7, connected-components

I have a list of integers, call L, where each integer in that list represents a node. I also have a dictionary called G, which represents a graph in the format `{node:[children]}`. What I am trying to do here is to determine if all the nodes L are in the same connected component in G. For example, if `L = [1, 2, 3]` and `G = {1:[2, 3], 2:[1], 3:[1]}`, the program should output `True` because in this case 1, 2, and 3 are all in the same connected component. However, in the case of `L = [1, 2, 3]` and `G = {1:[2], 2:[1], 3:[4]}` the program should output `False` because it is not possible to reach 1 and 2 from 3 and vice versa. My question is that is such as program possible? If it is, is it possible to do it in O(n)?

I have tried googling for an answer but I have only found results on how to check if two nodes are in the same connected component, not how to check if a list of nodes is in the same connected component. Any help will be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: I do not think this is possible in `O(n)`. You would at least need O(n^2) in my opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about something like this?

```
def check(g):
    i = 1
    for each in g.keys():
        if each != list(g.keys())[0]:
            for childs in list(g.values()):
                if each in childs:
                    i += 1
    return i == len(g.keys())



def check(g):
    i = 1
    for each in g.keys():
        if each != list(g.keys())[0]:
            if str(each) in str(g.values()):
                i += 1
    return i == len(g.keys())
```

Comment: Is it possible to solve this problem in O(n)? Thank you!

Comment: I will add an edit above, check if it works

Comment: `list(g.keys())` what is the big O for this?

Comment: This is still at least `O(n^2)` because of `str(each) in str(g.values)`

Comment: yeah makes sense :D I think I can't get it any better

Comment: @python_user, not sure, I really dont know much about time complexity

Comment: you can get log(n) if you memoize